# Convert int to High byte and low byte to be sent via usart using Modbus RTU

Tags: c, stm32

I am working on a program to be run on a STM32 microcontroller. The point is that I need to send the Modbus RTU telegram to control a device.

This would be the structure of the telegram:

```
uint8_t pBuffer [8] = { Address, Function, 
                        Register High byte, Register Low byte, 
                        Value High byte, Value Low byte, 
                        CRC High byte, CRC Low Byte};
```

Example:

```
uint8_t pBuffer [8] = {0x02,0x06,0x0C, 0x21,0x01,0xC7,0x9A, 0xA1};
```

And I send it via uart using:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, pBuffer, 8, 0xFFFF);
```

What I need at the moment to convert an int variable:

```
int freq = 455;
```

To the high byte and low byte:

```
high_byte = 0x01;
low_byte = 0xC7;
```

Which correspond to Value High byte and Value Low byte from the telegram

I tried to use sprintf:

```
int freq = 455;
char freq_hex[4];
sprintf(freq_hex, "%x", freq);
```

Comment: That would give you *text* of `"1c7"` which isn't what you want. Mask and shift.

Comment: How could I mask it?

Comment: For example, `pBuffer[0] = (freq >> 8) & 0xFF; pBuffer[1] = freq & 0xFF;`

Comment: `int value_to_mask = 0xffaa; short hi = value & 0xff00;` - for example.

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprintf` generates string output, that is not what you need here.

Simply:

```
uint8_t high_byte = (freq >> 8) & 0xff ;
uint8_t low_byte = freq & 0xff ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel like this was a very noob question.